# how to declare a function in structure in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, struct

I have stuck a point in my project i have to call a function inside the structure in xcode i wrote the c++ syntax for that but it gives error.. i have tried to search from net but did not found any solution.  i did not getting why it  is coming can any one help me .  any suggestion will be helpfull

```
struct containerPath
{

     int age() {return 10;}
   // void display();
};
```

[image]

Comment: I [cannot reproduce this error](http://ideone.com/Ye2vXL)

Comment: but my project is in objective c

Comment: Why did you tag it c++ then?

Comment: i have to use strucure in my objective  c project

Comment: Well, the c++ syntax is OK, as mentioned.

Comment: It's spelled **"function"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is a super set of C but not C++. Only C++ can have structure with methods. So make your controller file Objective-C++ by changing the .m to .mm.